# How can I interrogate user activity in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, reporting, business-intelligence

I'm looking for a way to best analyse the user data in our app.

for example

- how many users have read 0 articles on our site
- how many users have read 1 article on our site etc

we have a `users` table with `id`, `username` columns and we also have an `activities` table that creates an entry when an article is viewed. For example it would create a database row with

| id | activity | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | read | 1 |

all of the data we need is there, I just don't know how to interrogate to give that detail.

Comment: You can use Eloquent to retrieve that data, for example `Activity::all()` to retrive all activities, or `Activity::where(['user_id' => 1])->get()`  to retrieve activities of a user, you will need to create an Activity model for that activities table. You can also count activities `Activity::where(['user_id' => 1])->count()`

Comment: Not quite what's required.

Comment: Then i didn't understand, "how to interrogate" => how to fetch data from the database

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use an int code for activity and not a string.  So "read" would = 1, "edit"=2...etc   If you have no care about what user read with no association, that becomes easy by just setting a flag on the article that was read by article id.  So your article table would have:

```
id   article_id   activity   user_id
1     5             1         8675309
```

From there just do an eloquent query on article_id where activity = 1...

```
$articlecount = Article::where('article_id', $request->id)->where('activity', 1)->count();
```

$articlecount will give you all of the reads for that article.

If you need it based on user you could do a one to many relationship from your users models to articles models. Then query the user with(articles).  That will bring back all the articles where that user has activity. You could also specify in your eloquent to only bring back activity of reads/edits..etc too. In the same respect you could do the reverse and query the article and see all the users that have read that same article.

Comment: Yeah this is easy, but not quite what I'm looking for. I want a count of users that have read 0 articles, read 1 article etc.

Comment: Same principal. If you want no reads then it's just a case of doing looking for a null on activity for the user relationship. For a N amount, do a count of how many on the relationship.